# What happens when saving objects using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, guid

Probably sounds like a silly question, but there is an aspect about it I would like to know:

I'm working with objects that have a Guid-property for PrimaryKeys, which gets auto-generated in the database. I am using Entity Framework, Code First. If I do a Console.WriteLine with this property before saving, the value is
`00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.

After using Add and SaveChanges in the context, if I do a `Console.WriteLine` again with the same property, I have a value:
615f98eb-4ced-422a-877f-b9caa6f2b91f

Obviously, the object in memory has been updates. But I want to know how. The Guid is genereated in the database, so what happens?

Does the Guid-property of the object simply get updated from the database through EF, or does EF reload the entire object into memory after saving it in the database?

I would like to know, because that will determine how I design `NUnit-tests` in the same project.

Comment: You can use a tool like [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) to see the sql that is generated and send to the database.

Comment: It seems a little strange to me that you are using a SQL Server generated GUID. Generally the advantage of GUID Ids are that they can be client generated.

Comment: Genereally, but not always. ;-) It has it's uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EF object is updated when you call domainContext.SaveChanges(); Your new Id is generated by SQL database and value of Id is return value from DB. It is same for data types int, Guid and similar.

Answer (score 1):

EF does not only submit an Insert/Update statement, at the same time it does a get statement to retrieve the generated primary key. In fact it is one single query. Your entity's primary key is then updated with the retrieved one. No magic behind this.

That's also one of the reason why batch updates / inserts are not supported. Every entity has to be updated / inserted on its own.

This is a query that is being executed when inserting an entity with a computed int primary key:

```
insert [dbo].[TestTable]
       ([Name])
values ('myname' /* @0 */)

select [ID]
from   [dbo].[TestTable]
where  @@ROWCOUNT > 0
       and [ID] = scope_identity()
```

As you can see, the insert statement is followed by a select statement retrieving the computed columns (in this case ID). If there are more computed columns they're all selected here.